# How can I send pulseaudio streams over to another computer?

Tags: sound, 11.10, pulseaudio

I upgraded to Oneiric today and found out that I can't send my PA stream over to my desktop anymore. The same program that I used in Natty and before, papfrefs, is still there, but everything in the program is greyed out.

[image: paprefs]

How can I 'enable' this functionality again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/paprefs/+bug/829051) in the pulseaudio package, where pulseaudio fails to find the location of the modules it needs to load. As a workaround set a symlink to the module location by executing the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pulse-1.0 /usr/lib/pulse-1.0.0
```

**Note:** this workaround was tested in the current environment and may not work in the future (hopefully we don't need it any more when an update was is released)

Comment: congrats, you are the lucky winner! I had searched around for bug reports but it appears that you have more proficiency points spent in Google than I!