# How do I forward sound from one computer to another over the Lan?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, lan

I have two computers. Computer A is running Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome Clasic. Computer B is running Mythbuntu 11.10. Computer B has a sweet digital audio sound system.

I want to play music from Banshee on Computer A, but have the sound output sent over the LAN and come out on computer B's speakers.

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65784/how-can-i-send-pulseaudio-streams-over-to-another-computer) which indicated I should use something called "paprefs" to acheive this. So, I installed paprefs and then in the "Network Server" dialog, I selected these settings:

[image: paprefs]

And then... I have no idea what is supposed to happen. I checked the paprefs home page, and all they say under [Documentation](http://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/paprefs/#documentation) is "There is not much to say. Just run paprefs and see for yourself."

I don't see anything happening or any way I'm supposed to make the connection from Computer A to Computer B.

How is this supposed to work? Can someone provide clear instructions on what one does to actually make the connection?

Ideally, the hope is that I can have a set up that allows me to always play certain applications, like Banshee, over the LAN using Computer B's sound system. In other words, once set up, it is the default, and does not have to be manually reconnected every time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stream music over the network to multiple computers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The least complicated method to send audio from one Pulse Audio server to another over the LAN is to use the RTP/Multicast feature that you are able to set up using **[paprefs [image: Install paprefs]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/paprefs)**.

#### On the sender:

[image: paprefs screenshot showing "enable multicast/rtp sender" checked and "send audio from local speakers" selected]

Choose your local soundcard or choose a separate device you can select as audio output from *Audio Preferences*.

#### On the receiver:

[image: paprefs screenshot showing "enable multicast/rtp receiver" checked]

By doing so audio will be sent from the sender to the receiver via your LAN.

Comment: Thank you for this. I did this settings as you described, yet if I play Banshee on the Sender, I'm not hearing it on the Receiver. I also don't see any network sound device in pavucontrol or any gnome sound settings. Are there no other steps I need to take?

Comment: Got it sorted. I had to: 1. Reboot both machines. 2. On the Sender machine, go into sound settings, and under the "Output" tab, select the network sound device.

Comment: Just did this. Got *massive* lag and it made the server PC really sluggish... possibly something I'm doing wrong, but as it only involves ticking two checkboxes, I don't really know what _could_ go wrong.

Comment: @Greg: depending on your network, and on the audio content (bitrate!) this streaming method can be quite demanding. In case you have issues try to reset pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -k` this occasionally helps.

Comment: Pulseaudio has a "very high" priority. Maybe that's the reason for the sluggish server...

Answer (score 5):

The below example shows how to create a pulseaudio TCP tunnel to forward sound from computer `alpha` to computer `beta`.  In my case, both computers are running Ubuntu 14.04.

On `alpha` (the source computer) append the following lines to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
.fail
load-module  module-tunnel-sink  sink_name=beta  server=tcp:IP_ADDRESS_OF_BETA:4713
.nofail
```

(Choose any unique value for `sink_name`.  I arbitrarily chose to use the value `beta`.)

On `beta` (the destination computer) append the following line to `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module  module-native-protocol-tcp  auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;LAN_NAME
```

In the above, `LAN_NAME` and `IP_ADDRESS_OF_BETA` will be specific to your computers and your LAN.  For example, they might be:

```
LAN_NAME            =  192.168.1.0/24
IP_ADDRESS_OF_BETA  =  192.168.1.10
```

After making the above changes, restart pulseaudio, first on `beta`, then on `alpha`.  The order matters.  I restart pulseaudio with `pulseaudio --kill`.  I run `pulseaudio --kill` as my pesonal `UID` (not as root), as pulseaudio is already running as my personal `UID`.

If everything worked successfully, you should now see the tunnel on the `Output Devices` tab of `pavucontrol` on `alpha`.  When an audio source is playing, you should be able to route the source to the tunnel on the `Playback` tab of `pavucontrol` on `alpha`.

As long as the tunnel is intact, you should also be able to see the tunnel on the `Playback` tab of `pavucontrol` on `beta`.  If the tunnel disappears, restart pulseaudio, first on `beta`, then on `alpha`.  The tunnel is only created when `pulseaudio` starts on `alpha`.

Note 1: This example assumes pulseaudio is running on both `alpha` and `beta`.  As of 2016, pulseaudio runs by default on Ubuntu, and has for years.

Note 2: This example does not use Avahi Zero-configuration networking.  Avahi may be enabled by default on Ubuntu, but I have disabled Avahi on my systems.  On my LAN, `beta` (the destination computer) always has the same IP address, and I know that address.

Note 3: The above `auth-ip-acl` grants access to any device on the LAN.  Pulseaudio also supports other (more secure) authentication methods.  I use `auth-ip-acl` to simplify configuration.

More information can be found at the following pages:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8621/how-to-set-up-a-pulseaudio-sink
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/#index2h2
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index14h3

Comment: I was able to successfully implement the description in practice. Nevertheless, I had difficulties in that part of the description, which refers to the restarting of the `puleaudio`. The man-page of `pulseaudo` indicates: " -k | --kill
              Kill an already running PulseAudio daemon of the calling user". This command stops the `pulseaudio` and I must to launch `pulseaudio --start` in order to re-start the `pulseaudio`.

Comment: Back in 2016, I believe `pulseaudio` restarted automatically on Ubuntu.  I'm not sure why or how this restart happened.  At some point since 2016, this may have changed, and you may now (as of Dec 2022) need to (re)start `pulseaudio` manually, as @klpu39 describes.  I'm not sure exactly.  At present, I'm not streaming audio across machines.