# Can a Windows computer access Pulse sound server on an Ubuntu computer?

Tags: windows, networking, pulseaudio

With help I received in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70556/how-do-i-forward-sound-from-one-computer-to-another-over-the-lan), I set up all my Ubuntu computers so that they all access a central computer for sound output, using Pulse Audio Preferences.

I have some Windows computers as well. I was wondering if it is also possible to make them clients of the sound server computer, so that they will send their sound output over the network to be played by the Ubuntu computer running the Pulse audio sound server.

And if so, how?

### Update:

I came across this promising web page with instructions for getting a Windows computer to send audio to an Ubuntu Pulseaudio server, but it's too deep in technobabble for me to parse it into instructions to follow. http://t.motd.kr/en/archives/2228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [this](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/FAQ/#index15h3) section of PulseAudio FAQ.

Regards

Comment: An answer should contain more than just a link. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259.

Comment: This is not an answer anymore, as it's underlying linked webpage got removed altogether.

Comment: I fixed the link (edit pending review).

Answer (score 2):

There's a product called [Airfoil](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) the application needs to be installed on both machines. The Debs for linux are [HERE](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/linux/speakers.php) it's a paid program but there is a free trial. or use [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use something else that's established for broadcast, like Icecast. Windows has plenty of clients that can pick up a Icecast stream.

Takkat has already written a fairly decent set of options for [routing PulseAudio over Icecast](https://askubuntu.com/q/28498/449). That should get you up and running.

Alternatively there are [PulseAudio binaries for Windows](http://www.cendio.com/pulseaudio/). I've no idea how well they work, if at all, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

use http://bosmans.ch/pulseaudio/pulseaudio-1.1.zip unzip, edit files as this says: https://parseq.co.uk/wordpress/archives/setting-up-pulseaudio-1-0-beta-for-windows then run bin\pulseaudio.exe ignore the arugments given in the webpage