# How to stream audio via X11RDP

Tags: 12.04, sound, remote-x-session, x11rdp, xrdp

How can i stream audio from ubuntu 12.04 server to wyse s10 terminals using X11RDP?!

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial](http://lxer.com/module/newswire/ext_link.php?rid=168810)

Comment: @MITCH...Thanks for the tutorial but it talks about something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it since you must install pulse audio package on the client which is impossible to be done on the Wyse s10 terminal so no way to stream audio from an Ubuntu server to a Wyse s10 terminal

Answer (score 0):

As there is a proprietary implementation of fransferring of audio via a RDP connection on Windows ([Audio Output Virtual Channel Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240933%28v=prot.10%29)) but this feature is not available from X11RDP server (or VNC as a sidenote), where only basic remote protocols such as screen, keyboard, or mouse are present.

To be able to get the sound output of the server sent to a client we therefore need an additional protocol. Provided we had installed pulseaudio on our Wyse OS this can be done by using pulseaudio's inbuilt network features. These are all nicely documented and listed here:

[Pulse Audio Network Setup](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network)

The transfer methods may be set up by command line, or with a GUI using [paprefs](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/paprefs) [image: Install paprefs].

See also answers to these questions:

- [How do I forward sound from one computer to another over the Lan?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70556/how-do-i-forward-sound-from-one-computer-to-another-over-the-lan)
- [How to stream music over the network to multiple computers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers)

Comment: @Takkat...Thanks so much this is pretty but what i need between wyse s10 terminal and a computer and you  know i cant install any additional features to the wyse. Iam not working thin client i just use wyse as a dump terminal. do you have a solution for that?!!!

Comment: Features you will have on your Wyse entirely depend on the OS you run there. You should at least have pulseaudio installed to get this running. In case paprefs can not be installed on the client you need to include this network device in the default.pa settings file.