# Stream audio from VNC/RDP server

Tags: pulseaudio, rdp

My server is running Ubuntu 14.04. My laptop, which is running an RDP client, is also running Ubuntu 14.04. I want to connect to my server and be able to listen to videos over the connection.

**How do I stream audio over a remote desktop connection between two Ubuntu machines?**

**EDIT**: I just remembered that on some occasions I'll be using SSH port-forwarding, so any ports beyond 5900/3389 would need to be forwarded (if required).

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with RDP on Ubuntu (which has audio implemented for Windows) but you still may be interested in [my answer there](http://askubuntu.com/a/176880/3940).

Answer (score 0):

The RFB protocol (used by VNC) doesn't support audio, so this is not able to solve the issue.
Any remote desktop-viewing application will not give you a good frame-rate to watch videos. 
I recommend looking into streaming the media instead, there are a number of tools available to do this such as plex, and I personally use VLC for this myself.