# How to send sound using pulseaudio and shairplay to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pulseaudio, raspberrypi, airplay

I'm trying to use my Pi as a wireless Audio receiver.
I read airplay is a good and easy way to do this,
so I installed `shairplay` on my Pi. I can use the connected speakers via my Android smartphone with the app AirAudio.

Now I installed `paprefs` and `pulseaudio-module-raop`.
The AirPlay is also shown as an Audio Output device, but there is no sound.

Can anybody tell me why Ubuntu doesn't send sound to my Pi?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately at present the raop module shipped with pulseaudio does not support the newer RAOP2 protocol for AirPlay via UDP (rather than TCP). This however would be needed to stream audio to ShairPlay or newer AirPlay devices.

There is some effort to implement a RAOP2 module for PulseAudio (see [upstream bug #42804](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42804) and [pulseaudio-raop2 at Git](http://git.zx2c4.com/pulseaudio-raop2/about/)) but the work seems not to be finished yet.

Until then you may have a look at other streaming protocols to be able to send your audio to your RasPi (e.g. Bluetooth, [Pulse Audio sound server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers),  [PulseAudio RTP streams](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70556/how-do-i-forward-sound-from-one-computer-to-another-over-the-lan), [Icecast2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28496/how-do-i-setup-an-icecast-server-for-broadcasting-audio-in-my-network)).

Answer (score 1):

Use native PulseAudio network streaming instead of AirPlay

Tune PulseAudio on your Pi

load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/16
load-module module-zeroconf-publish
Apply settings by restarting PulseAudio and avahi

Then enable "Make discoverable PulseAudio network sound devices available locally" via paprefs on your desktop

While using wifi connection to remote PulseAudio you will need disable bgscan https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/373680/comments/54