# How to setup pulsaudio to stream to other pc?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, streaming

I have two identical machines running ubuntu 15.04. I want to stream audio from one machine to the other.

I have followed this thread to setup my client and server. [How to stream music over the network to multiple computers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers)

The problem is that the server is not discovered and doesnt show up in sound settings.

Suggestions?

Comment: Here's another link: http://askubuntu.com/a/70700/3940 for pulseaudio RTP network streaming.

Comment: Just tried that. No luck.

Comment: Is the pulseaudio daemon running in the other machine? Try ps aux|grep pulseaudio

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

For some reason the server settings done in paprefs were not saved to /etc/pulse/default.pa.

Uncommented in /etc/pulse/default.pa on the server:

```
load-module module-esound-protocol-tcp
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
load-module module-zeroconf-publish
```

Now everything works fine.

Thanks for your help!